# Problems after refreshing windows

Tags: windows-8

Laptop was constantly showing the BSOD and restarting, so I did the Windows 8 Refresh to repair it. I chose "keep my files option". But now everything is different and nothing works the same. I tried to use Netflix and "the balls" just go round n round in a circle, tried to download apps from Play Store and it just kept saying pending.

I've used every Microsoft software since dos but win8 just bamboozles me. Normally I can work my way around it and fix the problem but I just don't understand whats wrong or how to fix it.

Can anyone give me some pointer please or tell me whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it does not have network connectivity. Have you verified that the wireless adapter is configured to connect to the router (assuming wireless given that its a laptop)? First verify if you are getting an IP and able to ping the router, and then see if you can ping out to the net and/or resolve FQDN's.